# Kiel oni tradukas 'ETA' (Estimated Time of Arrival) esperante?

Tags: translation

Mi vidis ke tiu mallongaĵo ETA(Estimated Time of Arrival) ankaŭ estas uzata kiel projektaj datlimoj.

Kiel pli efiki traduki ĝin esperante?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tio estas ***proksimuma alventempo*** aŭ *proksimuma tempo de alveno*.

Anstataŭ *proksimuma* oni povas uzi *laŭtaksa, taksita, antaŭkalkulita*. Se vi preferas teni la akronimon *ETA*, mi sugestas ***ebla*** aŭ ***eventuala tempo de alveno*** ("potential time of arrival"). Notu ke tiuj vortoj ŝajnas malpli certaj ol *estimated*.

Comment: Mi ŝatas gardi la akronimon: eventuala tempo de alveno. Dankon!

Comment: Tiu respondo iom strecxas la signifon de "eventuala."

Answer (score 4):

Mi ne trovis pretan tradukon. Mi proponas "antaŭvidata alvenhoro".